# Existence of universal C++/Python Polyglot

Tags: python, c++

[Polyglot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) is a name given to programs that are valid in more than one language.

For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define do main()
do {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

is valid in C and Perl.

I am not a programmer, only a mathematician who was writing a few examples for the students. I was writing the the examples with both C++ and Python versions for their convenience, when I wondered of the posibility of having the two versions in the same file. I didn't know the existence of the term polyglot (refering to programs) or that they [can be such a source of fun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7261/write-a-polyglot-that-prints-the-languages-name).

My question is: Is it known a technique to have a *universal polyglot* for C++ and Python. By *universal* I mean that rather than being a single program, it is a template that allows to rewrite any (reasonably short) program in C++ and its version for Python into a polyglot that combines them.

Maybe I should ask first for existence of C++/Python polyglots, because in [my](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/poly/polyglot.htm) [searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)#External_links) I didn't see a C++/Python polyglot.

I posted it here because I wanted the polyglot for a slightly practical reason. I could post it in [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). If it should go there instead.

For me it is hard to judge the existence or materialize a solution. I don't have much experience on these clever constructions.

I tried enclosing the Python part between `#if 0` and `#endif`, which would be comments in Python and tell C++ to ignore that part. For the C++-usable part I tried enclosing it into the docstring, which for most effects would be ignored by Python. But couldn't find a way to make the quotation marks acceptable for both Python and C++.

```
#if 0
print('Hi there')
#endif
#if 0
"""
#endif
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
#if 0
"""
#endif
```

For C++, we got for `"""`:

> warning: missing terminating `"` character

Comment: That's a really cool question, because it seems like a Code Golf/Puzzle, but asking a question with out an answer there would not be too nice =D. I think asking about solvability of it is fine here, technical enough IMHO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C/C++, we can concatenate C-string.

`"""` is so the concatenation of empty string `""` with unfinished string.

To avoid this error/warning, you might use a variant: `""" "` and `" """`.

So you have concatenation of empty string with string with space in C++
and for python, you just have extra quote in your string.

Finally you have:

```
#if 0
print('Hi there')
#endif
#if 0
""" "
#endif
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl;
}
#if 0
" """
#endif
```

[C++ Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4345a58f3d58381)
[python Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/r1fkW-y37)

Comment: Ah, look at that! I did try putting more quotation marks, but I put them together thus breaking it for Python. Of course! Separating the inner one a bit was enough.

Comment: Nice ,  `"""#"` works as well