# Warning inside a preprocessor "#if 0" section

Tags: c++, g++, polyglot

So I have a polyglot header file that is included/imported from Python and C++. The part I'm insterested in looks like so:

```cpp
#pragma once 

#if 0
"""
#endif
constexpr int 
#if 0
"""
#endif
val = 2;
```

The idea is that Python code that imports it will see:

```py
"""
constexpr int 
"""
val = 2;
```

while C++ code that inculdes it will see

```cpp
constexpr int 
val = 2;
```

What I find strange I that I get the following warning (only when compiling in Linux):

> warning: missing terminating " character

And this can be shown in simple c++ [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9d73c95e6c44c71) (where the header is not included but defined inline)

The thing is that the `"""` sequence is mentioned inside an `#if 0` / `#endif` block. Why am I getting warnings for something that should be preprocessed out, and is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: While it's certainly a theoretical possibility, such things like that header file will quickly turn into an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's a very good option when you just want to define three numbers: major version, minor version and patch. A repo that has C++ and Python code both having to sync their APIs into a single version number, is pretty well organized if you can use a single place to bump those numbers

Comment: The stuff inside an untaken PP branch still has to consist of proper tokens. Tokenizing happens before preprocessing (and during once macros enter the picture).

Comment: Weighing in on the version number thing, that should probably be in the project build system. Each language used can have the build system generate whatever thing it needs to use the constants in that language.

Comment: For that I would rather recommend a single data-file, and during build/deployment autogenerate the correct source code.

Comment: Can't you keep only `val = 0;` in the file, and on the C++ side manually add `constexpr int` before including the header?

Comment: why not just leverage some build system and generate code by some script? For example translate python code into C++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That would do the trick. Problem is there's actually 3 numbers in that file (major, minor version and patch) so it wouldn't work. I can do [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d4758580c8fde2) to force a python comment and make the tokens valid. What chris said solved it for me

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you can always do it in an extra level of indirection. My experience is that people tend to forget to run these custom tools (so maybe everything works on CI/CD but not on local development), or the tools themselves need maintance, porting etc. I'd consider it if there was a third language in the mix, but atm we have TS in a different repo

Comment: Related to [existence-of-universal-c-python-polyglot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980076/existence-of-universal-c-python-polyglot).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discussion about whether this is a logical thing to do for OP aside:

For the purpose of a polyglot, this works without warnings:

```
#if 0
""""
#endif

constexpr int

#if 0
" """
#endif
val = 2;
```

The C++ compiler is now happy about matched quotes and for the python interpreter, the docstring now starts with a `"` and ends in `"` . The last space in the docstring is needed for python to recognize the triple quotes at the end.

Comment: got same solution one minute later :/

Comment: Here's another one https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64d4758580c8fde2 . What chris clarified in the comment was completely unknown to me. With that out of the way one devise many ways, but I couldn't fathom why there's warning in something that is excluded from the build process

Answer (score 3):

To fix your solution:

```cpp
#pragma once

#if 0
""" "
#endif
constexpr int 
#if 0
" """
#endif
val = 2;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cM6bf1r16
https://ideone.com/lbySQq